# how to make serialized async tasks

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, nsoperationqueue

i want to run some operations task with **completion**  **continuation- sequentially**

for example  i want to execute `getSomethingsWithResultWithCompletion` method for 3 times  as serialized tasks (like op1 depend op2 , ... depen op N ) :

```
[MFLayer getSomethingsWithResultWithCompletion:^(id  _Nullable response)Completion {

 // it will be run on another thread!** 
[MFRequestManager retrivesomeDataWithCompletion:^(id  _Nullable response1) {

 // it will be run on another thread!** 
  [MFRequestManager retriveAnothersomeDataWithInfo:response1 WithCompletion:^(id  _Nullable response2) {

      NSLog(@"Finished with Result : %@",response2);

 }];

 }];

}];
```

**Problem**

if `retrive methods` execute in another thread (like send a request with AFNetworking) i have a problem with serialize and another task will be start.

i have try With NSOperationQueue and Semaphore but still have a problem

i have implemented  something like this with `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` but implementation of them have run on the same thread so all of task start sequentially so it's works fine.
[operationQueueExample](https://github.com/mfarhand/operationQueueExample)

Comment: Could you change your "retrive" methods to "retrieve"?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly discourage that approach, but **if you send the task on a background thread**, you can use GCD semaphores.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[MFRequestManager retrivesomeDataWithCompletion:^(id  _Nullable response) {
   if(Completion) 
    Completion(response)
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
 }];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: yes i run my task on background thread but in `retrivesomeDataWithCompletion ` i will call another task on another thread and this cause problem ! would you please check the github link ?

Comment: can i implement them with `NSOperationQueue` too ?

Comment: your answer helping me but i'm confuse yet! if i have nested completion (update question) , how should i implement that ?

Comment: For nested completions you can use dispatch_group http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/

Comment: your answer is helping me, let me check for nested completions and notify you , do you have any approach with NSOperationBlock  ?

Comment: To work with async process you must wrap that process into an NSOperation, that you can add dependency between them. I do not have any approach but you can check the wwdc (2015 maybe) Advanced NSOperation where Apple explain that approach with also a good sample code

Comment: can you make an example with nested style ?
because i  have a problem with `dispatch_group_t`!
i mean it doesn't wait for complete